# How do I make a character selection page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.character1').eq(0).on('click',function(){
    location.href = 'index.html';
    $('.player1').eq(0).css('background','broly.png');
    console.log('this is working');
});
```

So basically the `character1` class is on `characterSelection.html` and the `player1` class is on the index.html page where they fight. When a character selects broly which is in `character1`, I want to change the `player1` class background image to broly.png. It relocates to the page fine, but it doesn't update the images. If I take this line out and run it alone. It will change just fine. What would be the best way at resolving this issue, so the user can select a character and utilize them on the `player1` class on the `index.html` page.

```
$('.player1').eq(0).css('background','broly.png');
```

Comment: before refreshing URL add some value to local-storage and on next page check that local-storage value and change according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a query string to `index.html`, parse the pass parameters at `jQuery()` call using `location.search`, `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.pop()` to get value passed from `characterSelection.html`

characterSelection.html

```
$('.character1').eq(0).on('click',function(){
    location.href = 'index.html?background=broly';
});
```

index.html

```
$(function() {
    if (/background/.test(location.search)) {
      var bg = location.search.split("=").pop();
      $('.player1').eq(0).css('background', bg + '.png');
      console.log('this is working');
    }
})
```